# Was bedeutet "norma­tiv gebo­te­ne Hand­lungs­op­ti­on"?

Tags: meaning

Bin auf folgenden Satz im Zusammenhang mit den Corona-Maßnahmen gestoßen:

> Die Kern­aus­sa­ge der Stel­lung­nah­me, dass ein „harter Lock­down“
> zum Zeit­punkt ihrer Veröf­fent­li­chung eine norma­tiv gebo­te­ne
> Hand­lungs­op­ti­on sei, beruh­te ausschlie­ß­lich auf den Einsich­ten
> von insge­samt 34 Wissen­schaft­le­rin­nen und Wissen­schaft­lern, die
> an der hoch­gra­dig inter­dis­zi­pli­nä­ren Arbeits­grup­pe
> mitge­wirkt haben.

Comment: "Normativ gebotene Handlungsoption" consists of three words, all of which can be found in dictionaries. Could you explain what remains unclear to you after looking up these words?

Comment: Sure. Still I can't grasp how these words together make sense. A "hard lockdown" was what at the time of publication? I don't understand how something can be "normativ geboten".

Comment: It basically means "This is what I want to do, but instead of a convincing argument, I beg the question and claim it is the only option". Compare "alternativlos".

Comment: alternativlos verstehe ich, denn es ist ja "geboten". Aber was heißt "normativ"?

Comment: "Normativ geboten" steht im Kontrast zu, etwa, "wirtschaftlich geboten" oder "ästhetisch geboten". Gemeint sind damit ethisch/moralische Normen. Normen gibt es natürlich auf vielen Ebenen, daher erschließt sich der Jargon nicht einfach aus den Einzelbegriffen, sondern man muss die Konventionen berücksichtigen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dinge können aus veschiedenen Gründen geboten sein, zum Beispiel könnte es moralisch geboten sein. Der Grund wäre also die Moral.
Normativ geboten... der Grund ist eine Norm. Diese Norm kann sich aber auf verschiedene Gebiete beziehen. Auf Wikipedia werden unter dem Stichwort "normativ" mehrere Teilbereiche angeführt.
In deinem Beispiel bezieht es sich eher auf eine Rechtsnorm. Dann würde es grob übersetzt "gesetzlich gebotene Handlungsoption" bedeuten.
Die Politiker sind beispielsweise gesetzlich zum Schutz der Bevölkerung verpflichtet, es können aber noch weitere Gesetze der Grund sein, warum man den harten lockdown anordnet als eine der Handlungsoptionen, die gesetzlich erlaubt sind oder notwendig sind.

Die Aussage deines Zitates ist, meines Erachtens, dass der harte lockdown nicht aufgrund einer gesetzlichen Vorgabe (=normativ) , sondern aufgrund wissenschaftlicher Meinung verordnet wurde.

Comment: also normativ = sich auf eine Norm beziehend

Answer (score 1):

*normativ geboten* is just another, rather technical/philosophical sounding way of saying "what should / ought to be done". So

> normativ gebotene Handlungsoption

translates to "the thing to do / the way to do it".

Comment: According to you "normativ" doesn't carry any information and I could just say "gebotene Handlungsoption"?

Comment: Yes, "normativ geboten" is a pleonasm.

Comment: I disagree. *Normativ geboten* says that there is some norm that says it should be done. A different case would be that it has to be done only because some person says so.

Answer (score 1):

(Die Frage wurde auf Deutsch gestellt, daher die Antwort auf Deutsch.)

*Handlungsoption* ist eine Möglichkeit (von mehreren), wie gehandelt werden kann.

*Geboten* bedeutet, dass eine bestimmte Option gewählt werden muss (oder eigentlich müsste).

*Normativ* bedeutet, dass eine Wertung oder ein Ideal zugrunde liegt. *Normativ geboten* bedeutet also, dass die Option nicht aus irgendwelchen Gründen, sondern aufgrund einer Wertung gewählt werden muss. *Geboten* impliziert *normativ* allerdings schon.

Zusammen bedeuten die drei Wörter also:

> Gemäß unserer Wertevorstellungen muss auf diese Weise gehandelt werden (hier: ein harter Lockdown eingeführt werden).

Comment: was versteht man denn unter "normativen Gründe" in diesem Fall? Dass das Gebot gilt, weil eine Richtlinie gefordert wird? Ich verstehe das Wort "normativ" hier nicht.

Comment: @LeeviL wie ich geschrieben habe: *es liegt eine Wertung oder ein Ideal zugrunde* <=> *es ist kein Naturgesetz, dass es geboten ist*. *Geboten* ist wohl meistens *normativ*, aber das wird hier gesondert betont. Die Formulierung *normative Gründe* war keine Tautologie, sondern sollte erst mal klarstellen, worauf sich *normativ* überhaupt bezieht, bevor es durch den nachfolgenden Halbsatz inhaltlich erklärt wird.

Comment: ich komme mir vor als hätte ich einen mentalen blinden Fleck. Kannst du einen Beispielsatz mit "normativ" geben? Wenn es "es liegt ein Ideal zugrunde" bedeutet, kann ich dann sagen, "ich lehne es normativ ab, an der Demonstration teilzunehmen"? Mein Problem scheint zu folgendes zu sein: intuitiv verstehe ich "normativ" als "einen Standard festlegend, eine Norm vorgebend".

Comment: @LeeviL Also verstandest du *normativ* bisher als *normierend*. Ich verstehe es so, dass es sich auf die Unterscheidung *deskriptiv/[normativ](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normativ)* bezieht und damit betont, dass der Schluss, dass etwas geboten ist, nicht auf deskriptiven Überlegungen beruht (das wäre das Gegenteil), sondern einen moralischen Kern aufweist.

Comment: Die Stellugnahme sagt also, dass die Handlungsoption nicht nach rein *deskriptiven*, sondern nach *normativen* Überlegungen geboten ist.

Comment: Ja, ich hatte es als normierend verstanden. Deine Unterscheidung deskriptiv / normativ hört sich interessant an. Kannst Du ein konkretes Beispiel für deskriptive Überlegungen und für normative Überlegungen geben? Etwas einfaches.

Comment: @LeeviL Grundsätzlich wäre z.B. die Aussage *es gibt einen Lockdown* deskriptiv und *es sollte einen Lockdown geben (weil ...)* normativ. Weiteres Beispiel: *der Lockdown umfasst die Schließung von Geschäften* (deskriptiv) und *der Lockdown ist gut/schlecht* (normativ). Für 'deskriptiv geboten' könnte man vielleicht gerade noch so ein Beispiel konstruieren: *(?)Die Forderung, die Erde als Kugel anzusehen, ist deskriptiv geboten*. Aber in den meisten Fällen ist *geboten* wohl immanent normativ oder die explizite Unterscheidung irrelevant.

Comment: Ok. Vielen dank für die Mühen. Ich gebe es auf das Wort wirklich zu verstehen ..

Answer (score 1):

Der Ausdruck "normativ geboten" ist ein philosophischer und juristischer Fachbegriff. Hier ein Zitat aus [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normativ):

> **Philosophie**
> Philosophische *Normativität* gibt an, wie etwas sein sollte (englisch: ought). Normativ ist in der Philosophie in der Regel dem Attribut deskriptiv (beschreibend) als Beschreibung für Theorien und Begriffe entgegengesetzt. Deskriptive Aussagen sind Sätze über die Realität und können überprüft und gegebenenfalls auch widerlegt werden (Falsifikation). Normative Sätze geben vor, wie etwas sein soll, also wie etwas zu bewerten ist. In der Moralphilosophie wird beispielsweise normativ geklärt, ob etwas gut oder böse ist oder welche Handlungen *moralisch geboten sind*.

Ein weiteres [Zitat](https://www.juraforum.de/lexikon/nothilfe) zeigt den Zusammenhang mit dem juristischen Begriff der Notwehr - bzw. Verteidigungshandlung:

> Unter einer Notwehrhandlung versteht man eine von einem Verteidigungswillen umfasste Verteidigungshandlung, welche
> - objektiv erforderlich und
> - *normativ geboten* ist,
> um den Angriff abzuwehren.

Der Kontext einer Verteidungshandlung gegen die Covid-Pandemie ist offensichtich.

Answer (score 0):

Duden [definiert](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/normativ) *normativ* als

> als Richtschnur, Norm dienend

Da die Aussage auf den Einsichten der Wissenschaftler beruht, ist davon auszugehen, dass *die Norm* hier eine wissenschaftliche Betrachtungsweise ist.

> Normativ geboten

hieße dann *aus wissenschaftlicher Sicht geboten*.

Da nun aber auch 34 Wissenschaftler die Welt nicht vollständig beleuchten können, bleibt es eine *Handlungsoption*.

Answer (score 0):

Eine normativ gebotene Handlungsoption ist ein als Standardhandlung verpflichtete Möglichkeit.
Obwohl nicht notwendigerweise sanktioniert erlaubt es nur begrenzt freie Wahl.
Man kann schlecht ohne Grund abweichend handeln ohne dass es einer zugerechnet wird.

Zahlungen in Euro sind in Deutschland auch eine normativ gebotene Handlungsoption.

Man kann zwar abweichend handeln, aber damit kommt man nicht weit.